# Automatic Failover in postgreSQL 14

Tags: postgresql, failover, postgresql-14, automatic-failover

I have read that PostgreSQL doesn't detect server failure so it doesn't do automatic failover, but all the articles were in 2020 (two years ago).

My question is **Does Postgres 14 need third-party software to do automatic failover?** or is it built-in now?

Comment: "*Does Postgres 14 need third-party software to do automatic failover?*" - yes. Which you could have easily found out yourself by reading the manual

Comment: PostgreSQL (like MySQL) is a single instance database (vs MongoDB, cassandra...) you need a custer manager (like pacemaker) to build a high availability architecture

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Google can answer this question in half a second

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you some of the third-party software I have done before:

1. repmgr: Infact, it's not automatic failover in case I have one master and 1 slave.
2. patroni: That is quite good.